# I need help properly forming this ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Basically, a User can participate in one or more events as either (or potentially both) a vendor and as a member of the event's faculty.

A user is, by default, categorized as neither a vendor nor a faculty member but rather attains either (or both) status(es) within the context of an event (e.g., the user has been admitted to an event as a member of its faculty).

It seems like what I want to say is that the user has many events through either (or both) the vendors or the faculty linking tables, but I'm not sure I'd go about representing this in my Rails model. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events through => vendors
  has_many :events through => faculty
end
```

Here's a sample of a query that I think I'd need to make:

```
Select * from vendors where user_id = 1;
Select * from faculty where user_id = 1;
```

Could someone provide some direction as to how to properly form this ActiveRecord association?

Update:

So, I've tried using single-table inheritance to solve the issue, and I've ended up with a user table which records containing only a single user type. While still using single-table inheritance, how do I get my users to have multiple types? (I know this is essentially a many-to-many relationship; I'm just not sure of how to accomplish this using STI.)

```
id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | city | zip_code | email |  type   |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+------------+-----------+------------+------+----------+-------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Akira      | Yamaoka   |            |      |          |       | Vendor  | 2014-08-30 14:58:26.917333 | 2014-08-30 14:58:26.917333
  2 | Pyramid    | Head      |            |      |          |       | Faculty | 2014-08-30 15:02:04.70209  | 2014-08-30 15:02:04.70209
```

Comment: Please provide queries you need to make on that data. Of course, the specified is not correct because you've listed two associations with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: I think, you can stick to `has_many ..., through ...` and use single table inheritance for establishing link types: common (not for direct use), member and vendor (inherited from common). I'll tell more when ready. Feel free to look at how STI works in the meantime.

Comment: I think I've figured out the single-table inheritance thing. I now have a User model from which the Faculty and Vendor models inherit. When I look at records within the Users table, I now see a field entitled "type" which contains the user's type--Faculty or Vendor. The problem is, as mentioned before, that a given user can (and probably will) be classified as multiple User types. For instance, a user could be both a faculty member and a vendor. What determines this is the event in which the user is participating. How do I allow a user to be classified as multiple user types?

Comment: I'll explain more in my answer, but you need to inherit a join model, not `User` or `Event` but something that links them together. I have some bits of working code, an answer with STI is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-table inheritance might be what you need. In a nutshell: it allows several classes with the same kind of data to be put into one table. The only requirement is that that table has a `type` column, a `string`.

Basically, it's about common sense. Let's say, a user can have passes to an event: a vendor's pass and a faculty member's pass. He might have both. Let's create a `Pass` model, bearing in mind that we'll need different kinds of it. But we'll use it later. For now let's just stick to `has_many through`:

```
rails g model Pass type:string user:references event:references
```

Migrate this and we won't need to modify our database anymore. We'll only modify Ruby. We should have got a class `Pass`, we'll need to mark its role in association:

```
class Pass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

All right. Then we'll have this sort of `User` and `Event`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :passes
  has_many :users, through: :passes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :passes
  has_many :events, through: :passes
end
```

Here's where the STI magic comes. Let's create two more classes.

```
rails g model VendorPass --no-migration --parent=Pass
rails g model FacultyPass --no-migration --parent=Pass
```

We've generated some classes without database tables (we don't need them). They are empty and we won't change it: they inherit a `Pass` and that's all we need. But we'll need to create some extra associations between our `User`, `Event` and the new passes. In the end, I've found this working:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # We already had this
  has_many :passes
  has_many :users, through: :passes

  # New stuff!
  has_many :vendor_passes
  has_many :vendors, through: :vendor_passes, source: :user

  has_many :faculty_passes
  has_many :faculty_members, through: :faculty_passes, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # We already had this
  has_many :passes
  has_many :events, through: :passes

  # New stuff!
  has_many :vendor_passes
  has_many :vendor_events, through: :vendor_passes, source: :event

  has_many :faculty_passes
  has_many :faculty_events, through: :faculty_passes, source: :event
end
```

Rails maintains its own understanding of `VendorPass` which is "it's a `Pass`, whose `type` is `VendorPass`", same with `FacultyPass`.

**The good parts:**

- Easy to imagine: data structure seems sane and logical
- We're free to add more types of `Pass`es without changing the database

**The bad parts:**

- No way to add extra fields to only specific subclasses of `Pass`: they're all in the same table
- Associations look a bit repetitive and cumbersome
- Rails only allows `type` to be a `string`, not the fastest type to compare

Comment: Thanks for making time to provide such an in-depth response. I think I see what you're doing here. I'm going to ponder this for a while.

Comment: This pretty well fits the bill. You rock, dude. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that every event has a ticket which is unique to an individual, an event and says whether the person is being admitted as a faculty member or vendor.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :events, through: :tickets
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :users, through: :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :faculty
end

class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end
```