# Single-table inheritance in Rails - How can I get a record within my table to have multiple sub-types while still using single-table inheritance?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to use single-table inheritance in Rails as a means of allowing a user have multiple user sub-types (e.g., faculty, vendor, etc.). I've ended up with a user table with records containing only a single user type. While still using single-table inheritance, how do I get my users to have multiple types? (I know this is essentially a many-to-many relationship; I'm just not sure of how to accomplish this using STI.)

```
id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | city | zip_code | email |  type   |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+------------+-----------+------------+------+----------+-------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Akira      | Yamaoka   |            |      |          |       | Vendor  | 2014-08-30 14:58:26.917333 | 2014-08-30 14:58:26.917333
  2 | Pyramid    | Head      |            |      |          |       | Faculty | 2014-08-30 15:02:04.70209  | 2014-08-30 15:02:04.70209
```

Here are my models' classes:

user.rb

```
1 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
2 end
```

vendor.rb

```
  1 class Vendor < User
  2   belongs_to :user
  3   belongs_to :event
  4 end
```

faculty.rb

```
1 class Faculty < User
2   belongs_to :user
3   belongs_to :event
4
5 end
```

Comment: why do you need `has_many :vendors` and all this relations between `User`, `Vendor`, `Faculty`? it looks little bit strange.

Comment: For single-table inheritance.

Comment: It isn't STI, it's something strange inside STI;)

Comment: ACk! Perhaps you're right. Getting rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

you could write something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Vendor < User
end

class Faculty < User
end
```

then get records with different types through `User` model, like `User.all`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply, but this response doesn't really address the original question, which concerned how one might go about giving a single model multiple sub-types simultaneously. Do you know how this could be accomplished? (Incidentally, my model classes look pretty similar to what you've posted. I've updated the original post to contain them, too.)

Comment: I have written how could looks your models with STI, what about multiple type for one user I'm not sure that with STI you could do that, even if `type` could be something like `[Vendor, Faculty]`, how ActiveRecord should chose which one type you need in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**A short answer: no, you can't do that, `type` column can only hold one value.**

**A longer answer:** a many-to-many relationship requires that an extra model exists (it has to, HABTM just won't do here) that contains references to a `User` and an `Event`. I called it a `Pass` [in this answer to your another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584930/2076787).

You should subclass a `Pass`, not `User`. And since `User` `has_many :passes`, which can possibly be `Pass` subclasses, a `User` can participate in an event in multiple ways: as a vendor or as a faculty member.

I've supplied some example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584930/2076787).